# how to take floor and capping for removing outliers

Tags: python, pandas

How to calculate 99% and 1% percentile as cap and floor for each column, the if value >= 99% percentile then redefine the value as the value of 99% percentile; similarly if value <= 1% percentile then redefine value as the value of 1% percentile

```
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1': np.random.randn(100), 'value2': np.random.randn(100)})
df['lrnval'] = np.where(np.random.random(df.shape[0])>=0.7, 'learning', 'validation')
```

if we have hundreds columns, can we use apply function instead of do loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Abdou's answer, the following might save you some time:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    percentiles = df[col].quantile([0.01, 0.99]).values
    df[col][df[col] <= percentiles[0]] = percentiles[0]
    df[col][df[col] >= percentiles[1]] = percentiles[1]
```

or use [numpy.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```py
import numpy as np
for col in df.columns:
    percentiles = df[col].quantile([0.01, 0.99]).values
    df[col] = np.clip(df[col], percentiles[0], percentiles[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first define a helper function that takes in as arguments a `series` and a `value` and changes that value according to the conditions mentioned above:

```
def scale_val(s, val):
    percentiles = s.quantile([0.01,0.99]).values
    if val <= percentiles[0]:
        return percentiles[0]
    elif val >= percentiles[1]:
        return percentiles[1]
    else:
        return val
```

Then you can use `pd.DataFrame.apply` and `pd.Series.apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda v: scale_val(s,v)))
```

Please note that this may be a somewhat slow solution if you are dealing with a large amount of data, but I would suggest you give a shot and see if it will solve your problem within a reasonable time.

#### Edit:

If you only want to get the percentiles for rows of `df` where the column `lrnval` is equal to "learning", you can modify the function to calculate the percentiles for only rows where that condition is true:

```
def scale_val2(s, val):
    percentiles = s[df.lrnval.eq('learning')].quantile([0.01,0.99]).values
    if val <= percentiles[0]:
        return percentiles[0]
    elif val >= percentiles[1]:
        return percentiles[1]
    else:
        return val
```

Since there is a column that contains strings, I assume that you won't be doing any calculations on it. So, I would change the code as follows:

```
df.filter(regex='[^lrnval]').apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda v: scale_val2(s,v)))
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: If table df has a column label 'learning' vs 'validation', how to modify the function to only calculate percentile by 'learning' but apply to the entire df table?